# EF Core 2.0 connection string in Azure Functions .NET Core

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework-core, azure-functions, ef-core-2.0

I'm using EF core 2.0 in Azure Functions using .net core. I'm trying to read db ConnectionString from local.settings.json, which is defined:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDbConnStr": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable() doesn't return any connection string info neither I can use ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings with .net core.
How do I access the connection string from the code?

Comment: How are you able to load EFCore 2.X with azure functions locally? I tried and it can't load EFCore. Are you using visual studio?

Comment: @DOMZE yep, using VS 2017, version 15.5.2 with .net core 2 Functions template

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.6" />
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: @DOMZE make sure you reference Sdk.Functions 1.0.6 and 2.0.0 EF. There is currently Azure Functions .NET Core bug

Comment: @DOMZE https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/625#issuecomment-351563570

Comment: You my friend are a savior! thanks so much.

Comment: hahahaha. yeah, I wasted a few hours of my life on that as well...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use one of the helper classes in `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host`:

```
AmbientConnectionStringProvider.Instance.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnStr")
```

This class is delegating the work to internal class called `ConfigurationUtility`, which does something in line with

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true)
    .Build();
var conn = configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnStr");
```

Comment: Wow! It works! Thanks! It's not documented anywhere. I would never have guessed it...

Comment: It is documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration
Configuration has simple enough mechanism to load config from env/json/ini.

Comment: How do I use any other configuration variable, not a connection string. It's not working with custom parameters

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`. The keys are "ConnectionStrings:YourKey"

Assuming your local.settings.json looks like the following:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "sqldb_connection": "connection_string_here"
  }
}
```

Use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings:sqldb_connection", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);`
to get the value

Comment: That works during local dev, but how do you set this value in the Azure portal?