# How to use Connection String in Azure functions for EF Core 2.1

Tags: entity-framework-6, azure-functions, ef-core-2.0

When using Entity Framework 6+ I can have a class inherit form DbContext like this

```
MyContext : DbContext
```

Then I could use the code like this

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
        ...
        }
```

As long as I had a configuration file with connection string settings with the same name this would be picked up by Entity Framework. Quite nice for different environments.

Now I am working with Azure Functions running on .NET CORE, .NET STANDARD and Entity Framework Core 2.1

But I cant figure out how to achieve the same. Even though there is a dedicated section for ConnectionStrings in Azure Function app and i would expect the local.seeting.json with an input like this

```
  {
      "IsEncrypted": false,
      "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
      },
      "ConnectionStrings": {
        "MyContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyContext;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0"
      }
    }
```

should do the same. But no.

All the samples I can find is where you have to inject the DbContextOptionsBuilder or a connection string into the constructor.

But since it is Azure Function and DI framework dont play that well with it I rather avoid to pass the connection string or db context all the way down the layers.

In short: Can EF Core not pick up the settings from a file itself?

Comment: Here is a similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806064/ef-core-2-0-connection-string-in-azure-functions-net-core) you could refer to.